# Cufon font not working. Anyone please advise?

Tags: html, css, cufon

I am unable to use this Cufon font on a website. Is there anything wrong with the code? I have attached a screenshot of the code. Not sure why the code is not implemented properly using the  tags.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1DKS.jpg

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: You're not loading the cufon js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not loading the cufon js file.

Here's how to use Cufon:

https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/Usage

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Playing with Cufón</title>
        <!-- Stylesheets here, before all scripts. Helps avoid styling issues. -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <!--
        If you want to use complex selectors with Cufón, load a selector engine (JavaScript framework) here.
        We support jQuery, Sizzle, MooTools, Dojo, Prototype and other popular frameworks.
        -->
        <script src="cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="YourFont.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Cufon.replace('h1'); // Works without a selector engine
            Cufon.replace('#sub1'); // Requires a selector engine for IE 6-7, see above
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Your custom font here</h1>
        <h2 id="sub1">Your custom font here too</h2>
        <!-- To avoid delays, initialize Cufón before other scripts at the bottom -->
        <script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script>
        <!-- Google Analytics and other scripts here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No worries, glad to be of help.